# Sorting objects based on a string value property in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, enums

I have an array of objects and the definition for an object looks something like this:

```
export class AccountInfo {
  accountUid: string;
  userType: string;
  firstName: string;
  middleName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

*NOTE: The reason I don't have userType as an enum is because the object is populated by a database call and I couldn't figure out a clean way to have the string returned from the db populate the enum.*

I want to sort the array so that objects with a userType of 'STAFF' appear first, followed by 'TEACHER', then 'PARENT', then 'STUDENT'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can store the order in an `array`, then just use `indexOf` with `sort` to achieve your goal. See the code example below:

```js
const humans = [{
  accountUid: "1",
  userType: "TEACHER",
}, {
  accountUid: "2",
  userType: "STAFF",
}, {
  accountUid: "3",
  userType: "STUDENT",
}, {
  accountUid: "4",
  userType: "PARENT",
}];

const order = ['STAFF', 'TEACHER', 'PARENT', 'STUDENT'];

const result = humans.sort((a, b) => order.indexOf(a.userType) - order.indexOf(b.userType));

console.log(result)
```

If you can't use ES6, just use:

```
humans.sort(function(a, b){
    return order.indexOf(a.userType) - order.indexOf(b.userType);
});
```

Comment: Elegant way to do it.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I noticed a few other responses to this question originally that were less elegant but after seeing this solution they must have removed their posts. Either way, this was not only a good and efficient solution, but your answer was very thorough thanks to the use of mock data. Props to you sir/madame!

Comment: doesn't work for me. It says that boolean cannot be converted to number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, probably have an order object to store the orders

```
const actionOrder = {
    "EAT" : 1,
    "SLEEP" : 2,
    "PLAY" : 3,
} as const;

const users = [{
    name: "Mike",
    action: "PLAY"
}, {
    name: "John",
    action: "EAT"
}, {
    name: "Harry",
    action: "SLEEP"
}
];

users.sort((a,b) => {
    return actionOrder[a.action] - actionOrder[b.action];
});

console.log(users);
```